# how to put focus on textfield after showing error in j2me?

Tags: java-me

```
void getThisAlert(String Title,  Displayable txtagency2)
{
    Alert error = new Alert("", Title, null, AlertType.INFO);
    error.setTimeout(2000);
    Display.getDisplay(myProject).setCurrent(error,txtagency2);
}
```

i am validating lots of data.. so after show user that he has not filled some particular detail and afterward i want to put focus on it.... so somebody will please provide some solution...

As i can put focus on to some other page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `callSerially` method of `Display` object avec a class implements `Runnable`.

```
private class ItemFocusEventHandler implements Runnable
{
     private Item _Item = null;

     public ItemFocusEventHandler(Item item)
     {
          _Item = item;
     }

     public void run()
     {
          try { Thread.sleep(1000); }
          catch (Throwable t) { ; }

          _display.setCurrentItem(_Item); // sets focus to item
     }
}
```

Then in data validation routine

```
if (_txtName.getString().length() == 0))
{
     Alert alert = new Alert(null, "Name ?", null, AlertType.ERROR);
     alert.setTimeout(2500);
     _display.setCurrent(alert, this);
     _display.callSerially(new ItemFocusEventHandler(_txtName));
}
```

This way focus will receive to `_txtName`. You can use that handler for other UI element as well.